# What does h indicate in this diagram of avl trees?

Tags: avl-trees

Looking at the tree on the left it seems that the triangles represent leaves of the avl tree.  To arrive at the balancing of -2 besides the node y the right subtree must have 2 nodes while the left subtree has a maximum of 4 nodes. Thus 2-4 = -2. However what does the h indicate?

[image: avl tree]

Comment: The triangles are usually used to represent subtrees. And the $h$ is the height of the subtree. The integer beside a node is the height differences of its subtrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably the height of the subtrees, i.e. the length of a longest path from the root to a leaf. Doing the balancing leaves us with a tree of height $h+2$ where we started with height $h+3$.